# Выделить из строки первые две координаты и последние две

Tags: json, php, синтаксический-анализ

Вот собственно в таком виде есть строка. Нужна с помощью средств php выделить из этой строки первые две координаты и последние две в виде `$coord1_first_lat $coord1_first_lon $coord2_first_lon...` ну в общем понятно. Просто я не знаком с пхп, с++, java - на них я могу это парсить, но так вышло что нужно на пхп. Спасибо за терпение.

```
[{"lon":"30.4585","lat":"50.50654"},{"lon":"30.45833","lat":"50.50699"},{"lon":"30.45804","lat":"50.50778"},{"lon":"30.45784","lat":"50.50834"},{"lon":"30.45763","lat":"50.50901"},{"lon":"30.45763","lat":"50.50901"},{"lon":"30.45822","lat":"50.50907"},{"lon":"30.45878","lat":"50.50912"},{"lon":"30.46052","lat":"50.50933"},{"lon":"30.46209","lat":"50.50946"},{"lon":"30.46243","lat":"50.50949"},{"lon":"30.46243","lat":"50.50949"},{"lon":"30.46294","lat":"50.50859"},{"lon":"30.46355","lat":"50.50755"},{"lon":"30.46398","lat":"50.50683"},{"lon":"30.46438","lat":"50.50611"},{"lon":"30.46451","lat":"50.50592"},{"lon":"30.46462","lat":"50.50566"},{"lon":"30.46462","lat":"50.50566"},{"lon":"30.46555","lat":"50.50566"},{"lon":"30.46661","lat":"50.50563"},{"lon":"30.4668","lat":"50.50563"},{"lon":"30.46704","lat":"50.50563"},{"lon":"30.46732","lat":"50.50563"},{"lon":"30.46777","lat":"50.50566"},{"lon":"30.46807","lat":"50.50568"},{"lon":"30.46839","lat":"50.50573"},{"lon":"30.46878","lat":"50.50577"},{"lon":"30.4707","lat":"50.50604"},{"lon":"30.47168","lat":"50.50618"},{"lon":"30.47168","lat":"50.50618"},{"lon":"30.47184","lat":"50.50584"},{"lon":"30.47184","lat":"50.50584"},{"lon":"30.47138","lat":"50.50576"},{"lon":"30.47135","lat":"50.50576"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$json = 'тут_ваша_строка';

$array = json_decode($json, true);
/* На этом можно было бы закончить... */
$from_start = array_slice($array, 0, 2); # 2 элемента, начиная с начала
$from_end = array_slice($array, -2);     # 2 элемента, начиная с конца

/* Формируем вывод, как нужно автору */
foreach ($from_start as $k => $v) {
    $num = $k + 1;
    ${"coord{$num}_first_lon"} = $v['lon'];
    ${"coord{$num}_first_lat"} = $v['lat'];
}
foreach ($from_end as $k => $v) {
    $num = $k + 1;
    ${"coord{$num}_last_lon"} = $v['lon'];
    ${"coord{$num}_last_lat"} = $v['lat'];
}
```

---

**Проверка**

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($coord1_first_lon . " -- " . $coord1_first_lat);
var_dump($coord2_first_lon . " -- " . $coord2_first_lat);
var_dump($coord1_last_lon . " -- " . $coord1_last_lat);
var_dump($coord2_last_lon . " -- " . $coord2_last_lat);
echo "</pre>";

/*
string(19) "30.4585 -- 50.50654"
string(20) "30.45833 -- 50.50699"
string(20) "30.47138 -- 50.50576"
string(20) "30.47135 -- 50.50576"
*/
```

Comment: это изящно спасибо

Comment: а что означают {""}  я смогу потом пользоваться этими переменными ${"coord{$num}_first_lon"} для своих целей или это просто вывод?

Answer (score 1):

Твоя строка имеет JSON-формат. В пхп есть встроенная функция `json_decode`.
Вызови её для своей строки: `$array = json_decode( $json_string, true);`

`$array` будет содержать массив хешей. Для удобства распечатай `print_r`

Comment: это я знал что она имеет такой формат, просто пхп никогда не учил

Answer (score -2):

```
$coord = '[{"lon":"30.4585","lat":"50.50654"},{"lon":"30.45833","lat":"50.50699"},{"lon":"30.45804","lat":"50.50778"},{"lon":"30.45784","lat":"50.50834"},{"lon":"30.45763","lat":"50.50901"},{"lon":"30.45763","lat":"50.50901"},{"lon":"30.45822","lat":"50.50907"},{"lon":"30.45878","lat":"50.50912"},{"lon":"30.46052","lat":"50.50933"},{"lon":"30.46209","lat":"50.50946"},{"lon":"30.46243","lat":"50.50949"},{"lon":"30.46243","lat":"50.50949"},{"lon":"30.46294","lat":"50.50859"},{"lon":"30.46355","lat":"50.50755"},{"lon":"30.46398","lat":"50.50683"},{"lon":"30.46438","lat":"50.50611"},{"lon":"30.46451","lat":"50.50592"},{"lon":"30.46462","lat":"50.50566"},{"lon":"30.46462","lat":"50.50566"},{"lon":"30.46555","lat":"50.50566"},{"lon":"30.46661","lat":"50.50563"},{"lon":"30.4668","lat":"50.50563"},{"lon":"30.46704","lat":"50.50563"},{"lon":"30.46732","lat":"50.50563"},{"lon":"30.46777","lat":"50.50566"},{"lon":"30.46807","lat":"50.50568"},{"lon":"30.46839","lat":"50.50573"},{"lon":"30.46878","lat":"50.50577"},{"lon":"30.4707","lat":"50.50604"},{"lon":"30.47168","lat":"50.50618"},{"lon":"30.47168","lat":"50.50618"},{"lon":"30.47184","lat":"50.50584"},{"lon":"30.47184","lat":"50.50584"},{"lon":"30.47138","lat":"50.50576"},{"lon":"30.47135","lat":"50.50576"}]';

$ar = explode("},{", $coord); #разбиваем строку используя разделитель },{ .
$coordAr['1'] = reset($ar); # Устанавливаем указатель на начало массива и забираем первые координаты.
$coordAr['2'] = next($ar); # Передвигаем указатель на следующую позицию(вторую) и забираем вторые координаты.
$coordAr['4'] = end($ar); # передвигаем указатель на последний элемент массива и забираем последние координаты.
$coordAr['3'] = prev($ar); # передвигаем указатель на одну позицию назад и забираем предпоследние координаты.

# Прогоняем полученный массив в цикле и ищем с помощью регулярного выражения.
foreach($coordAr as $key => $value){
    preg_match('!"lon":"([0-9/.]*)","lat":"([0-9/.]*)"!',$value,$result[$key]);
}
print_r($result);
```

Результат выполнения:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => "lon":"30.4585","lat":"50.50654"
            [1] => 30.4585
            [2] => 50.50654
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => "lon":"30.45833","lat":"50.50699"
            [1] => 30.45833
            [2] => 50.50699
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => "lon":"30.47135","lat":"50.50576"
            [1] => 30.47135
            [2] => 50.50576
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => "lon":"30.47138","lat":"50.50576"
            [1] => 30.47138
            [2] => 50.50576
        )

)
```

Comment: За что вы так с JSON? Что он вам плохого сделал? :)

Comment: php 5.5 
PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function json_encode()

Привык писать код который будет работать под разными версиями. Конечно же хорошо использовать доп. библиотеки (в данном случае для версии 5.5  уже есть расширение php5-json), но не всегда есть возможность до установить их на тех веб-серверах на которых будет находится написанный код.

Comment: @terantul, какой хостер НЕ будет устанавливать этот пакет?

Comment: @terantul, в реальном мире хостинг выбирается под продукт, а не продукт пишется под хостинг.

Comment: мсье знает толк в извращениях